# What secondary statements possible after receiving individual risk probability from black box model?

Tags: conditional-probability, reporting

Suppose I have a model that predicts the probability of some event (e.g. likelihood of cancer).
For the sick (red) and healthy (green) individuals in a holdout set (not used to train the model), we might see something like the following distribution:

[image]

Now, suppose I ask the model for an individual's prediction of probability (it spits "given your factors your probability of cancer is p=0.35").

Given the above information (individual's probability and the predicted probabilities and true outcomes of a test set), what other statistically sound statements be made for this individual?

Some examples might include:

- risk percentile
- risk ratio vs mean of the healthy population
- the local reliabilty of the model  ("in this percentile around p, the model predicted 75% positive cases - in our test set we observed 70% positive cases (n=302)"). This gives a measure of 'confidence' in the individuals prediction, which may differ as p varies (is it one you'd use?).

What other secondary statistics may be derived?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "more valid"?

Comment: Okay, "valid" = "statistically sound."  But that's awfully vague.  What are you trying to get at?

Comment: Have updated the question a little, but I mean "statistically sound" statements related to specific individual. For example, can we say whether this probability estimate is more certain that others, or provide other measures of confidence that relate to the individual?

Comment: Let's strip your question to its essentials.  You have told us that *all* you know about an individual is the probability of an event as given to you by a black box.  What more could you possibly hope for from such limited information?

Comment: We also know the distribution of probability estimate for the test population. For this we can know, what percentile of risk the individual lies at, or the ratio of their risk vs the healthy population mean (for instances). If you have a (probability-producing) black box model, a test set, what can you report about the individual?

Comment: Of what relevance is the distribution of all results?  This is an individual with their own characteristics, whereas the distribution reflects the distributions of characteristics of other individuals you have dropped into the black box.  You seem to be saying that you have a probability but you want to read something more out of it than what a probability actually means.

Comment: Well -- a test sample should usually be able to test a black box model, so I assume we have it. If we have it then we can calculate, for example, confusion matrix derived measures (TPR, FPR, precision, ... etc), for various cut-point probabilities. These statistics relate to population, however, GIVEN, that data of the individual prediction are there new statistics that are sensible to report -- for example, how reliable is the model around the individual's probability (it may vary across the range).

Comment: Your plot is similar to a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution), so you could for example compute something like Pr[red|p] = red[p]/(red[p]+green[p]), where red[p] is your red histogram. But this would be essentially training a mixture model on the holdout set, using the "trained model p" as a new feature.